# how to make post request with oAuth2 token authentication

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

This code did not work:

```
createRoute(FormRoute) {
    var body = "&name=" + FormRoute.name + "&description="+ FormRoute.description ;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
    headers.append('Authorization',  'oauth ' + localStorage.getItem("access_token"));
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.post('url', body, {headers: headers})
        .toPromise()
        .then((response) =>
        {
            var res = response.json();
            console.log(res);
            resolve(response.json());
        })
        .catch((error) =>
        {
            var err = error.json();
            console.error("err");
            console.error(err["error_description"]);
            let alert = this.alert.create({
              title: 'Error',
              subTitle: err["error_description"],
              buttons: ['OK']
            });
            alert.present();
        });
    });
}
```

OPTIONS 'http://url'  401 (Unauthorized)

Failed to load 'http://url': Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401.

Comment: You need to configure CORS on the server side.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: research about CORS and you will understand it.

Comment: I am installing CROS on chrome and it is not the problem .
The problem is how to send token oauth2 in header in post request

Comment: The problem is CORS. Preflight options 401 is always CORS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42221602/response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-401-angular

Comment: @canillas you are right
solved
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following line of code is the culprit here.

```
this.http.post('url', body, {headers: headers})
```

I don't think you are trying to post to `http://url` as it doesn't make any sense.

Change it into following.

```
this.http.post(url, body, {headers: headers})
```

Define your url somewhere like:

```
var url = 'http://httpbin.org/'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i add the url like you did
i got error
 (index):1 Failed to load http://.../api/: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401.